# How to get JWT token in SecurityContextHolder in Spring Boot OAuth2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a resource server which is receiving requests with valid Bearer token. I can either use `@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt token` for all requests where I need to get claims from the token or I should be able to get the user information from `SecurityContextHolder` right? I would like to get it from the context holder. I would assume I need to define jwt converter in my `SecurityConfig`? I cannot find any information on the recommended approach.

The code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333945/accessing-a-spring-oauth-2-jwt-payload-inside-the-resource-server-controller) works with some legacy versions of spring security... I am using the newest spring boot with Spring security 5.4.2

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    private String jwkSetUri;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/test/**").authenticated()
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/test/**").authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("entGrps");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are plan to *use spring-security-oauth2-resource-server* dependency,
I think would be better to use `@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt token` to get token's claims.

That's simplier and less boilerplate code.

But that's up to you, Imranmadbar's solution is also working)

Answer (score 0):

If you want information from **SecurityContextHolder**, you have to keep it on there.

Here is the **easiest solution** for this:

1. Get Auth **Token** from the **request**, where your **current log user info** present.
2. Extract log **user name** from **jwt** using some Util method.
3. Get the **user details** from the Database using this user name.
4. Finally **Set this User info** into the Spring Security context holder.

And you have to do this every Request Using an HTTP Request Filter (OncePerRequestFilter).

Like:

```
        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
        import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
        import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
        import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
        import com.madbarsoft.config.MyUserDetailsService;
        import com.madbarsoft.utility.JwtUitl;

        @Component
        public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {    
                    
                    @Autowired
                    private JwtUitl jwtUitl;
                    
                    @Autowired
                    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService; 

                    @Override
                    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chin)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                        
                        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
                        System.out.println("Authorization Header #:"+authorizationHeader);
                        
                        String userName = null;
                        String jwtStr = null;
                        
                        if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
                            jwtStr = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                            userName = jwtUitl.extractUserName(jwtStr);
                            System.out.println("Form JWT userName: "+userName);
                        }
                        System.out.println("In Filter Before set #: "+SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
                        if(userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
                            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
                            if(jwtUitl.validateToken(jwtStr, userDetails)){
                                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                            }
                            System.out.println("In Filter After Set #: "+SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
                        }
                        chin.doFilter(request, response);
                    
                    }
                }
```

Now you can access user info from anywhere in the Entire Project.

(It's a working Project, You can take some info from [gitLink](https://github.com/imrangthub/jwt-with-spring-security/tree/master/src/main/java/com/madbarsoft/auth) here.)

Answer (score 0):

If our only concern is to retrieve the token from the header, the simplest solution I came up with is to use the DefaultBearerTokenResolver:

```
public class CheckAuthTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
        String token = new DefaultBearerTokenResolver().resolve((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    }
}
```